# Logrotate with `copytruncate` "data loss" - is it serious?

Tags: linux, logrotate, log-rotation, data-integrity, centralized-logging

Manpage of logrotate claims that using `copytruncate` option leads to "*a very small time slice between  copying  the  file  and  truncating it, so some logging data might be lost*". Is it actually relevant in real world scenarios?

I'm using logrotate paired with rsyslog for gathering network statistics and logs from networking devices and servers. There's plenty of logs. I'd say around 10-20 messages per second. Should I be worried about this gap?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your requirements how much inaccuracy you can take because of it. To find out exactly how much effect it has, you have to test your use case.

There are so many things depending on your individual use case that we cannot provide a "yes" or "no" answer.